# Send data and get result from Azure Machine Learning Studio by Ionic mobile app

Tags: ionic-framework, azure-mobile-services, azure-machine-learning-service

I have a classification model in Azure Machine Learning Studio. I need to send data to this model and get the predicted result by Ionic mobile app.
I have model API. I need request and response sample code.

Answer (score 1):

Try using

```
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http'
```

Add the HttpClientModule to the imports array in src/app/app.module.ts:

```
imports: [
    BrowserModule, 
    HttpClientModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(), 
    AppRoutingModule
  ],
```

With the HttpClientModule set up, we then need to inject the HttpClient into any class where we want to launch an HTTP request.
As AML Studio accepts only POST requests you need to use the post feature:

```
this.http.post(url, {
    headers: {'Content-Type':'application/json', 'Authorization':('Bearer '+ your_api_key)},
    body: your_request_body
}).subscribe((response) => {
    console.log(response);
});
```

Usually your url looks like

> https://europewest.services.azureml.net/workspaces/workspace-id/services/service-id/execute?api-version=2.0&details=true

And your request body is defined in the experiment. It's usually available on the web service page (where you have Python/R/C# code samples).

Hope you'll find this helpful.